# Using nameFilters for excluding a particular type of items

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse's plugin extentions we can have pop up menus applicable for particular item depending on the type we specify in the nameFilter field. But now i want it to be reversed, 
means I want this pop up menu not to be shown for some types of items(based on its extensions).

So is it possible. Need help badly. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't try it, but...

```
<viewerContribution
        id="IlexGuiConsole.viewerContribution2"
        targetID="IlexGuiConsole.viewerContribution2">
     <action
           class="ilexguiconsole.Action2"
           id="IlexGuiConsole.action2"
           label="label">
        <enablement>
           <not>
              <objectClass
                    name="ilexguiconsole.Object2">
              </objectClass>
           </not>
        </enablement>
     </action>
  </viewerContribution>
```

Comment: excluding some particular types. can you elaborate little bit nanda. Thanks

Comment: Thanks nanda. If i want to not enable this for more than one type of item then do i have to add one more objectClass clause. any help